# background-image with filter:blur causes edges to be 'caved in' on a 'fade-in' effect

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a wrapper that has a background image that is fullscreen

```
<div class="bg-img"> </div>

.bg-img {
  background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/f9u8ET4.jpg");
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  filter:blur(8px);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

and once this goes full screen, the corner become caved in because of the blur. I figured this was an easy fix just by adjusting the width & height and then increasing the top and left offset by a bit to hide the cave in.

```
.bg-img {
  background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/f9u8ET4.jpg");
  position:fixed;
  top:-20px; // adjust the cave in
  left:-20px; // adjust the cave in
  height:125%; // adjust the cave in
  width:125%; // adjust the cave in
  filter:blur(8px);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Which worked fine. But this wrapper of mine is a popup up which I wanted to fade in. I created a simple `fadeIn` animation:

```
@keyframes fadeIn {
  from { opacity: 0; }
  to   { opacity: 1; }
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
.fadeIn {
  animation: fadeIn 1s linear;
}
```

upon playing the animation, you see this 'cave in' effect in which I'm referring too, it's like the image is readjusting to the new width and height that I've defined. I've included a snippet to better show my bug.

I'm not sure how to remove this undesired re-adjustment. To be honest, it's not totally certain it's a re-adjustment issue, it's as if the `fadeIn` animation just *jumps* near the end.

```js
function displayImage() {
  var image = document.getElementById("bg");
  image.classList.remove("hidden");
  image.classList.add("fadeIn");
}
```

```css
.bg-img {
  background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/f9u8ET4.jpg");
  position: fixed;
  top: -20px;
  left: -20px;
  height: 125%;
  width: 125%;
  filter: blur(8px);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.fadeIn {
  animation: fadeIn 1s linear;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="displayImage();">Show Image</button>
<div id="bg" class="hidden bg-img"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's more of a hack than a solution but I normally use a nested divs where the outer one is enlarged and animated while the inner one has the bg image and blurred. here is an example:

```js
function displayImage() {
  var image = document.getElementById("bg_wrapper");
  image.classList.add("fadeIn");
}
```

```css
.bg_wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  transform: scale(1.1);
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: all 1s;
}
.bg-img {
  background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/f9u8ET4.jpg");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  filter: blur(8px);
}

.bg_wrapper.fadeIn {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="displayImage();">Show Image</button>
<div id="bg_wrapper" class="bg_wrapper"><div id="bg" class="bg-img"></div></div>
```